# Cartthrob - Paypal Express error 10416

Tags: cartthrob, paypal, shopping-cart

I have a cartthrob setup selling 30 day access to channel entries. A customer purchased access but the payment didn't go through paypal express giving the error "10416 Transaction refused because of an invalid argument."

Customer was still able to access the channel entry even though the payment hadn't completed.

I feel this is a paypal express problem more that a CT one but wondering if anyone here has experienced similar issues and what the workaround is (other than not using paypal)

Running EE 2.5.5 and CT 2.3.4 for what it's worth

Comment: Some further info on the paypal error code:          The error code 10416 on a DoExpressCheckoutPayment attempt indicates that you have attempted to complete an Express Checkout transaction too many times.  An Express Checkout token is only valid for 10 transaction attempts, or for 3 hours, whichever occurs first.  If you receive a 10416 error, restart the Express Checkout process from the beginning with a new SetExpressCheckout request.

Comment: Payment attempt not showing on paypal end. The real problem here is that whatever happened on the paypal end Carthrob has allowed access to the entry without payment actually completing.